# How do I achieve this kind of layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

What is it called and what kind of library should I use so I can make one like it?

[image]

Comment: using constraint layout you can make like you want

Comment: Show us what you tried. Update your question with xml code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can be created by using collapsingtoolbar layout along with FAB a.k.a Floating action button . ImageView is placed inside collapsingtoolbar. 
For more information see this answer :
[Collapsing toolbar with FAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32550361/collapsing-toolbar-with-image-tabs-and-fab)

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know what it was called. Now I can start from there :)